# Spring Boot & Jersey - AuthenticationFilter - No session in endpoint

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jersey-2.0

I have an Authorization filter in Jersey that authenticates and retrieves the User object from DB. I pass this user object via a custom SecurityContext to the endpoint.

```
@Transactional
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
 requestContext.setSecurityContext(new SecurityContext() {
            @Override
            public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
                return new UserInfo(userService.findById(1));
            }
        });
     ...}
```

I retrieve the object at the endpoint with a SecurityContext.

```
@Transactional
 public Response endpoint(@Context SecurityContext securityContext){
             UserInfo userInfo = (UserInfo) securityContext.getUserPrincipal();
        }
```

I then try to initialize a lazy loaded collection of children with:

```
 Hibernate.initialize(userInfo.getUser().getChildren());
```

I still get the error

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: user.children, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

I've tried with and without @Transactional on some/all methods involved to no avail.

The children must be lazy loaded due to performance reasons. I do not want to retrieve them with each authentication.
The easy alternative here is to return an attribute to the SecurityContext, but that would be doing 2 database calls for the same user object in almost every endpoint that makes use of the user object.

Comment: Change your children from list to set

Comment: done that, no avail. running out of ideas..

Comment: Did you make your userService transactional? Are you sure you have transactionManager configured correctly?

Comment: Yes I did make it transactional.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the transaction manager setup? I'm quite new to spring boot. Did not do any special config besides auto configurations.